# spork executable can't be found after bundle installing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, spork

I've added `spork-rails` to my Gemfile, under a `:test` section, and run `bundle install`. `bundle show spork` now gives `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc2`

However, now when I do `spork cuc`, bash tells me `The program 'spork' is not currently installed`. And if I try `bundle exec spork cuc`, I get `bundler: command not found: spork`.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try to replace
 group :test
with
 group :test, :development do

Comment: Still have problem?
Do You use RVM or RBENV or Vanilla Ruby?

Comment: My setup's changed completely - I now run under Windows, via RailsInstaller. I did try spork again, and got it "running"; however, some cucumber tests that succeed without it fail with it. I haven't yet spent the time to figure that out, although I might soon.